# how to activate Conda in Cmder

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cmder

I use Cmder as my command line and I've just installed Anaconda and I want to work with Conda in a Cmder session instead of opening the anaconda prompt.
It doesn't understand the `conda` command, Of course and when I navigate to the path I installed Anaconda in and try to run `_conda.exe acrivate base` gives me this:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.     
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your                                     
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.                                                       
                                                                                           
To initialize your shell, run                                                                  
                                                                                           
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>                                                                  
                                                                                           
Currently supported shells are:                                                                
  - bash                                                                                       
  - cmd.exe                                                                                    
  - fish                                                                                       
  - tcsh                                                                                       
  - xonsh                                                                                      
  - zsh                                                                                        
  - powershell                                                                                 
                                                                                           
See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.                                      
                                                                                           
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine just running `conda init cmd.exe`.

After that, restart cmder and you should be able to access `conda` in the default cmder shell.

More details in this:
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/anaconda-python-cmder-integration-on-windows-10-2

Answer (score 0):

I use

`"%windir%\System32\cmd.exe" /K "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat [environment-name]"`

This should activate the environment.